# Jquery Datatable Horizontal Scroll bar disappears with intermittently

Tags: jquery, datatables

Jquery Datatable Horizontal Scroll bar disappears intermittently.
Recently added a footer  element to exist data table which was working fine.
After adding  having issues with scroll bar disappearing intermittently
during:
   - pagination appears in some whilst not in other pages 
   - window resize can see horizontal scroll bar appear and then disappear

Data Table width become absolute rather than  100% based on the container size.

**THE PROBLEM**

Scrollbar/Data table performs a calculation to determine width of grid table.
With the introduction grid footer, the dynamic resizing of the grid has a knock effect on the horizontal scrollbar appearance.

The complication is that grid tabs, pagination will affect the dynamic resizing hence the inconsistency of the scrollbar

**THE CODE**

plnkr.co/edit/JEo3T0MAmQEJUqXh9kpx?p=preview

**THE FIX**
The code fix is quite simple, ensure table width is below threshold so that the scrollbar will always appear.

**ATTEMPTS TO RESOLVE ISSUE**

1)       "sScrollXInner": "400%", ==>     "sScrollXInner": "100%"

- seems to work in most scenarios
- large number of columns / overflow   (Resolved)
- small number of columns / overflow   (Outstanding)

2) Remove $scope.options fixedHeader

"fixedHeader": { header: false, footer: true  },

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1)  JQuery DataTable POC APP!
https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/DLUvGZUStDaTvNLzKhIl/

2) Resize table

Comment: You should add relevant code. Like the HTML (and JavaScript).

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/JEo3T0MAmQEJUqXh9kpx?p=preview

Comment: Add your code here in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.DTFC_ScrollWrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

In my case this code resolves the issue